# Why does Brad Wesley call Cody "Elvis"?

Tags: character, roadhouse

In [*Roadhouse*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098206/) Brad Wesley offers to buy the firefighters a drink after they tried to save Red Webster's store.

The house band at the Double Deuce bar is led by the lead singer and guitar player named Cody (portrayed by the late, great Jeff Healey).  Brad calls him "Elvis" on two separate occasions during this scene.

> It's like a morgue in here.  Play something Elvis.
>
> Elvis, play something with balls.

**Why does Brad Wesley call Cody "Elvis"?**

Comment: I haven't seen the movie, but isn't it just a humorous way of referring to someone that is a singer (especially in a bar house band, which makes him as distant from a pop star as possible)? Something like calling a college athlete "Bolt" or a TV commercial actor "Pacino". Sawyer in _Lost_ had a habit of nicknaming people like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Because he's an arrogant a**hole

Brad Wesley doesn't give two hoots about anybody but himself or at least those in his immediate sphere of influence...and even then he treats them like cr*p.

He weaves across the road when driving, he disturbs his neighbour across the lake etc. etc.

Here, he's just throwing a vaguely relevant name out in a mean-sprited way because he doesn't know, or care about, the name of the singer.